# github - how to divert commits to another pull request from the same branch

Tags: git, github

In a Github pull request, it says `Add more commits by pushing to the XYZ branch on ABC`

Without creating a new branch and before closing current pull request, is it possible to push new commits from `XYZ` branch to a new pull request that I open?

Or will all pushes from `XYZ` go into currently open pull request?

Comment: all commits pushed on the `XYZ` branch will be added to the PR

Answer (score 0):

In short: 1) no. 2) yes.

Pull requests (or merge requests) are based on changes between branches. You're asking the maintainer to merge the changes made in said branch to the upstream branch. If you push commits to the branch you're asking for them to be merged as well. Those commits will also appear in the pull request because it is added to the difference between the two branches.

If you create another pull request with the same branch, the same changes will be shown for both pull requests. You're better off creating separate branches per pull request.